# Apply difference function on each adjacent row value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below and want to see if timestamps are always increasing.
Basically a diff in each row for timestamp column. Add diff in a third column.

```
A,B,Timestamp
5,58330831,1491375186654664218
5,58330832,1491375186654673017
5,58330833,1491375186654687270
5,58330834,1491375186654696695
5,58330835,1491375186654712416
```

Comment: Did you check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff)?

Comment: Do you need `df['dif'] = df.Timestamp.diff()` ? or `df['dif'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp).diff()` ?

Comment: I just need to check if timestamps are in increasing sequence. Preferable show the difference in adjacent timestamp in a new column `df['dif'] = df.Timestamp.diff()` works. But i need to now check if this new column is increasing (ascending always)

Comment: df1[df1['diff']<0] works

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
df['diff'] = (df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].shift(1))>0
```

First one will be `False` as it has no value to compare and returns `NaN`.

Comment: What does `.shift(1))>0` do. I know how columns can be subtracted easily, but never tried on adjacent rows. Thanks

Comment: `shift(1)` shifts all rows by one. And `>0` checks if difference is positive.

Comment: and how doe python get to know that it has to iterate/loop over every row?

Comment: when you subtract columns you subtract them row by row.